# Use $\epsilon - \delta$ definition of continuity

Tags: real-analysis

Show that the following function is continuous on their domain for:

$f(x) = |x|$

Not sure if this is the best way.

Let $f$ be a function with domain $\cal{D}(f)$ and $(-\infty,0)\cap(0,\infty) \subset \cal{D}(f)$. We say that $f$ is continuous on  $(-\infty,0)\cap(0,\infty)$ if, given any $\epsilon > 0$ and $x_0 \in (-\infty,0)\cap(0,\infty)$ there is a number $\delta(x_0, \epsilon)$ such that if $|x|\in \cal{D}(f)$ and $||x| - x_0| < \delta(x_0,\epsilon)$, then $|f(|x|) - f(x_0)| < \epsilon$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\epsilon>0$ and consider $x_0 \in \Bbb{R}$.

If $x_0>0$, then let $\delta= \min\{ \epsilon, x_0/2\}$. If $|x-x_0|<\delta$ then note $|x|=x$ and $|x_0|=x_0$ so $||x|-|x_0|| <\delta \leq \epsilon$.

If $x_0<0$, similar argument.

If $x_0=0$ then let $\delta = \epsilon$ and if $|x|<\delta$ then $||x|-|0||<\delta=\epsilon$.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me somewhat over-complicating the problem.

Another way:

If $c \in \Bbb{R}$, then $x \in \Bbb{R}$ only if
$$
\big| |x| - |c| \big| \leq |x-c|
$$
by triangle inequality;
given any $\varepsilon > 0$, we have $|x-c| < \varepsilon$ only if $\big| |x| - |c| \big| < \varepsilon$; so taking $\delta := \varepsilon$ suffices.